# Why does TIdFTP appear to corrupt media files?

Tags: http, ftp, corruption, indy10

I am using TIdFTP version 10.6.2.5366.

If I download a media file (a .ts video file) using TIdHTTP, everything is fine.  But if I download the same file using TIdFTP, the media file won't play.

Both files are identical in size on the destination drive, but the contents are quite different (I have looked at them using a file comparison utility).

Is there a reason why the IdFTP appears to corrupt the media file?  Are there specific settings I need to change to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you are transferring the files in ASCII mode (the default) instead of in BINARY mode.  In ASCII mode, bytes representing textual line breaks are normalized, which can corrupt a binary file, like a video.

Make sure you set the `TIdFTP.TransferType` property to `ftBinary` before transferring a non-textual file.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the explanation - unless the Indy code is wrong.  I have checked that I am using ftBinary as the TransferMode, and I have also checked that the last SendCmd I can find in the IdFTP.pas file before the download starts is "Type I"

Comment: @Andrew Then you are just going to have to debug into it further. In the usual case, `TIdFTP.Get()` will simply use `TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` to read+save the server's file data exactly as it is sent. Unless compression is involved (do you have a `Compressor` assigned to `TIdFTP`?), then things are a little more complicated. But you did not offer ANY details about your setup OR the nature of the corruption (you said you compared the files, but you did not explain what was actually different about them). So I can't help you any further without more details.

Comment: I was hoping I was missing something obvious, hence the lack of detail / code.  I am not using a compressor.  I am just trying to copy the file.  I am using Delphi 10.2, and am using TIdFP out of the box apart from setting transfer mode to ftBinary.  The file comparison utility showed that after about the first 5 bytes or so, there was little similarity in the contents.  Think I am out of my depth trying to debug further!

Comment: If SSL/TLS is not used to secure the connections, you can use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to view the raw data exactly as the FTP server is sending it. If SSL/TLS is used, you can instead assign a `TIdLog...` or `TIdConnectionIntercept` component to the `TIdFTP.DataChannel.Intercept` property in the `TIdFTP.OnDataChannelCreate` event to see what data Indy is receiving after decryption. Either way will help you determine whether the problem is in how the server is sending the data, or in how `TIdFTP` is interpreting the data.

Comment: Thank you.  I still think this might be beyond me, but I will have a look when I have some time.  But my code for the download is really simple ...with IdFTP do
  begin
    if not (Connected) then
      Connect;

    ChangeDir(SourcePath);
    TransferType := ftBinary;
    Get(SourceFile, DestinationFile, True, ResumeSupported);
  end;

Comment: You should not set the `AResume` parameter of `TIdFTP.Get()` to the return value of the `TIdFTP.ResumeSupported()` method. Set `AResume` to *your* intention - `False` if you are downloading the file anew, or `True` if you are trying to resume a previously broken transfer (in which case `ACanOverwrite` should be False instead of True). `TIdFTP.Get()` calls `ResumeSupported()` internally for you and adjusts the transfer accordingly. I don't *think* that would cause your corruption problem, but it is something to be aware of. Otherwise, I don't see anything else wrong with your code.